# array variable to also update when an element is deleted in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code below

```
const myID = [] //global variable

const tableContents = () = {

const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([])
const doChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    setSelectedOptions([...selectedOptions])

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(selectedOptions).length; i++) {
      myID[i] = selectedOptions[i].id
    }
  }
}
console.log(myID)
```

The function `doChange` is triggered by `onChange` of a component (Filter button) that has options. Each of the options has an `id`. What I initially wanted to do is put the `id's` of the chosen options in an array so that I can pass it as a value of a query. The problem is when I choose multiple options and remove one, the array that displays still includes the id of the deleted option.

For example:
Chosen options are `option1`, `option2`, `option3`. When `console.log(myID)` is executed, `1,2,3` would appear. When I remove `option3`, the same `1,2,3` would still appear. How do I structure the code wherein when I remove an option, the array displayed will also be updated?

Comment: Why don't you use useReducer hook instead of useState. You should always use useState when you want to store a data type like number or string. But when you want to store an array or object, you should always go for useReducer. Maybe that can even solve your problem.

Comment: How are you removing `option3` in your code?